# How to use clone and append and return the first instance of the img

Tags: jquery

I'm using the clone append to return a image to a new div , but the div i am cloning has several instances of the same image , and i only want to retrieve 1 copy. Can you use a selector in the following , like find the 1st instance of the image only ?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#divOLD").find("img#franchiseicon_0000").clone().appendTo('#divNEW');
});
```

Comment: are you saying there are multipe image tag with same id

Comment: can you show your html it will be better to understand the problem with html

Comment: By _the first instance_ do you mean the _first child_? It's a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this clones the first `img` in the `#divOLD` and appends it to `#divNEW` if that is in fact what you meant to say:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#divOLD img").eq(0).clone().appendTo('#divNEW');
});
```

if you need to do it with a selector you can try:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#divOLD img:first").clone().appendTo('#divNEW');
});
```

or

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#divOLD img:eq(0)").clone().appendTo('#divNEW');
});
```

Comment: perfect thank you , i thought there was a selector :)

Comment: @MShack there is a selector as well: ``$("#divOLD img:first")``

Comment: @meni181818 yes, and also its equivalent `:first-child`